# Change SharePoint 2016 site header

Tags: css, 2016, header

I have SharePoint 2016 and I want to change the following which is by default in my header going from left to right:

1. remove the menu in blue background with small square icons (I don't want this menu to appear);
2. Change "SharePoint" text to something else and
3. Remove "Sites" Link.

[image]

There are other options on the right of this header section but I'm fine with those options.

Your support is really appreciated

Answer (score 5):

I added the following CSS to the "Site Setting > Look and Feel > Master Page" and in there I updated "Alternate CSS URL" to point to my CSS file:

```
.o365cs-nav-appTitle {
    display: none !important;
}


.o365cs-nav-appTitleLine {
    display: none !important;
}

span.o365cs-nav-brandingText {
  color: transparent;
}

span.o365cs-nav-brandingText::after {
 content: "Problem Management System";
 color: white;
 position: relative; 
left: -5em; 
}

#O365_MainLink_NavMenu{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your design using CSS and JavaScript.

```
#O365_MainLink_NavMenu{display:none;} //it hides app launcher

//this one hides "sites"
.o365cs-nav-appTitle {
    display: none !important;
}

//this hides line between sharepoint and sites text
.o365cs-nav-appTitleLine {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I am updating text SharePoint to current web title using jQuery

```
//this script updates text SharePoint to your current web title
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".o365cs-nav-bposLogo span").text(_spPageContextInfo.webTitle);
}
```

My suite bar converted as below[image]

Comment: nice, thank you very much,where should I add this code?